# Access arrays in elastic queries

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have documents containing arrays - sometimes with duplicates

```
   {
        "_index" : "indexx_v1-2020.11",
        "_type" : "x-logs",
        "_id" : "wZ_p_XUBV4a6COay8wWzJ",
        "_score" : 10.089222,
        "_source" : {
          "actiontype" : "doit",
          "geoip" : {
              // geographic data
          },
          "data" : {
            "field" : [
              "foo",
              "bar",
              "foo",
              "bar"
            ],
          },
          "@version" : "1",
          "header" : {
            "product" : "our_product",
            "processGUID" : "6528",
          }
        }
      },

      {
        "_index" : "indexx_v1-2020.11",
        "_type" : "x-logs",
        "_id" : "xJq-_XVWV3f6COaXnRqx",
        "_score" : 9.089443,
        "_source" : {
          "actiontype" : "doit",
          "geoip" : {
              // geographic data
          },
          "data" : {
            "field" : [
              "foo",
              "bar"
            ],
          },
          "@version" : "1",
          "header" : {
            "product" : "our_product",
            "processGUID" : "3456",
          }
        }
      },
```

If I access these fields using painless script with the *doc* syntax dupliates are removed:

So

`doc['data.field'].length`

returns 2 for both documents.

This prevents me from filtering with script as this expression is never true

```
"script": {
   "script" : { 
      "inline": """
          return doc['data.field'].length > 2 &&
                 doc['data.field'][2] == 'foo' &&
                 doc['data.field'][3] == 'bar';
           }
      }
```

Any hint for a newbee to either filter for these different documents or build aggegrates in order to count these to variants

```
foo/bar           : 1 document
foo/bar/foo/bar   : 1 document
```

Thanks

Comment: what do you expect to get ?

Comment: Does [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/find-separately-store-array-duplicates/108175) article on discuss.elastic.co help?

Comment: > what do you expect to get

I would like to aggregate and treat those two sample documents as different entities.
I could not find a way to filter them separately.

I already saw the artitle linked by @tomr but I was not able to transfer it to by problem

Comment: Are you in control of the ingest pipeline? If so, please describe it

Comment: @tomr - Actual I do not even know that pipeline.
I am only using the Kibana console to enter queries manually

Comment: Can you update the question with an example of a complete document?